# Send eMail in Windows Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

Is it possible to send an email message in a Windows Universal App for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1?

```
await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:abc@abc.com?subject=MySubject&body=MyContent"));
```

With this code line I can send an email, but I want to send a message with attachment.

Answer (score 5):

Since Microsoft missed to add EmailMessage and EmailManager to the Windows Store Apps libraries it seems as if there are only two unsatisfactory solutions: You could use sharing or initiate email sending via the mailto protocol. Here is how I did it:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Initiates sending an e-mail over the default e-mail application by 
  /// opening a mailto URL with the given data.
  /// </summary>
  public static async void SendEmailOverMailTo(string recipient, string cc, 
     string bcc, string subject, string body)
  {
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(recipient))
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("recipient must not be null or emtpy");
     }
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(subject))
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("subject must not be null or emtpy");
     }
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
     {
        throw new ArgumentException("body must not be null or emtpy");
     }

     // Encode subject and body of the email so that it at least largely 
     // corresponds to the mailto protocol (that expects a percent encoding 
     // for certain special characters)
     string encodedSubject = WebUtility.UrlEncode(subject).Replace("+", " ");
     string encodedBody = WebUtility.UrlEncode(body).Replace("+", " ");

     // Create a mailto URI
     Uri mailtoUri = new Uri("mailto:" + recipient + "?subject=" +
        encodedSubject +
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cc) == false ? "&cc=" + cc : null) +
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bcc) == false ? "&bcc=" + bcc : null) +
        "&body=" + encodedBody);

     // Execute the default application for the mailto protocol
     await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailtoUri);
  }
```

Comment: Sneaky.  I like this.

Comment: Somehow I missed the attachment. Should work by adding "&attachment=<filepath>" to the URI.

Comment: this will not work if you have attachment.  attachments are ignored if you try to create new email from a UWP app and add attachment.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows Phone 8.1

You could use the following to send email with attachment:

```
var email = new EmailMessage(); 
email.To = ...;
email.Body = ...;
email.Attachments.Add( ... );
var ignore = EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email);
```

### Windows 8.1

On Windows 8.1, unfortunately, there is no way to send email with attachment. The **mailto** protocol is all you have and it doesn't not officially supports attachment. However, you can add attachment as the following:

> mailto:xxx@xxx.com?subject=xxx&body=xxx&attach=C:\path\to\file

or

> mailto:xxx@xxx.com?subject=xxx&body=xxx&Attachment=C:\path\to\file

But it is up to the client to decide whether it will handle the attachment or not. See this thread for more detail https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767737(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: using EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync wont work on Windows 10 desktop environment using Outlook as default email app.

Comment: you just have to run it on the main ui thread to get Outlook to launch. Wrap the message logic in  Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,

Answer (score 0):

To send emails with attachment You would be needed to use the `EmailMessage` and `EmailManager` class.

**1. EmailMessage:**

The EmailMessage class defines the actual email that will be sent. You can specify the recipients (To , CC , BC) , Subject and the Body of the email .

**2. EmailManager:**

The EmailManager class is defined in the Windows.ApplicationModel.Email namespace . The EmailManager class provides a static method ShowComposeNewEmailAsync which accepts the EmailMessage as argument . The ShowComposeNewEmailAsync will launch the Compose email Screen with the EmailMessage which allows the users to send an email message.

You can find more reference here [windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-runtime-apps-how-to-2-send-emails-with-attachment-in-wp-8-1](http://mobileosgeek.com/windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-runtime-apps-how-to-2-send-emails-with-attachment-in-wp-8-1/)

Comment: Currently this doesn't work on a universal app. Because the namespace Windows.ApplicationModel.Email doesn't exists. So the clases EmailMessage and EmailManager can't be accessed.

Comment: EmailMessage and EmailManager are obviously only available in Silverlight applications. Windows.ApplicationModel.Email does not exist in Windows Store Apps hence a Universal App project cannot access this namespace.

Answer (score 0):

On this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871373.aspx

Microsoft supplies a example how to share with your application. Download the source example app: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=231511

Open the solution and add a file: test.txt to the project root.

Then open ShareFiles.xaml.cs and replace the class with:

```
public sealed partial class ShareText : SDKTemplate.Common.SharePage
{
    public ShareText()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        LoadList();
    }

    List<Windows.Storage.IStorageItem> list { get; set; }

    public async void LoadList()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///test.txt");
        var item = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
        list = new List<IStorageItem>();
        list.Add(item);
    }


    protected override bool GetShareContent(DataRequest request)
    {
        bool succeeded = false;

        string dataPackageText = TextToShare.Text;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataPackageText))
        {
            DataPackage requestData = request.Data;
            requestData.Properties.Title = TitleInputBox.Text;
            requestData.Properties.Description = DescriptionInputBox.Text; // The description is optional.
            requestData.Properties.ContentSourceApplicationLink = ApplicationLink;
            requestData.SetText(dataPackageText);
            requestData.SetStorageItems(list);
            succeeded = true;
        }
        else
        {
            request.FailWithDisplayText("Enter the text you would like to share and try again.");
        }
        return succeeded;
    }

}
```

Might not be the best code, but it helped me :)