# How send email with attachment in a Windows 8.1 universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

How can I send an email with an attachment in a Windows universal app (Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1) ?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646815/send-email-in-windows-universal-app)

Answer (score 0):

```
EmailMessage objEmail = new EmailMessage();
objEmail.Subject = "Abundantcode Article";
var localAppFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var fileHandle = await localAppFolder.CreateFileAsync("AbundantcodeData.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
objEmail.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(fileHandle.Name, fileHandle));
await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(objEmail);
```

Comment: `EmailMessage` is not available under Windows Universal App 8.1

Comment: Yes thank you for bringing that up, saw it works only for win phone 8.1.
During my research found your answer to a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24646815/send-email-in-windows-universal-app)